# CSS Code Lost in TFS Checkin

Tags: tfs

I recently checked in some code (a CSS file) into TFS after someone else had also made some changes and it appears to have lost some of the previous changes. I'd normally expect an automerge to happen or a conflict error, but it just seemed to lose code.

Has anyone had this happen and is there any diagnoses/reasons why this could happen?

Comment: Have you checked the change/submit log?

Comment: how do I do that? I can see the history. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. You should see the other person's commit and what they committed, and then see your own commit, and see what changed.
Normally if your lines do not conflit it should automerge, but it might help you figure out what happend.

Comment: Thanks. I did that but it seems to be very different. I also looked at my log and there was no mention of it doing an "Automatically resolved conflict"

Comment: Which TFS and VS version? in VS 2012 and above you can choose to show deleted items from the Source Control Explorer